Permissions not working and wont let me create a file
I keep trying to create this on visual Studios but it doesn't work, it is my own system and ive tried to fix it multiple different ways does anyone know any fixes[enter image description here]enter image description here
I tried to fix it via running as admin, uninstalling and reinstalling, changing permissions, disabling antivirus, having everything else shutdown. I have no idea what else i could do

From the image you provided this is a permission issue which indicate that you do not have write access to that folder.As you are using Windows Authentication you need to ensure that the account you are using can write to that folder.GO to the explorer and right click the issue folder,select more options and choose give access to,then add write access for your current account.
